# Example encoding video using FFMPEG for Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am working on an Android app, that needs to do the following:
- capture a (animated) view to video including audio (from a mp3 file)
- encode the captured video (probably a bunch of raw image buffers) and audio to avi.

After searching, FFMPEG seems the most suitable. Does anybody have a sample code to accomplish what I need. I would really appreciate.

Whyhow

Comment: it is not an animated view is is a Preview or CameraView that will capture each frame from the camera and will send it to the encoder. Same logic to the audio, you will capture every sample and sent it to the encoder. Then the encoder will combine both in a file or as a stream.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in this site. Always be specific and make your best effort before asking, and don't treat Stack Overflow as a repository of tutorials. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http:s//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by 'a (animated) view' to capture, but be aware that android apps running with normal permissions cannot access the raw framebuffer.  The computation part of ffmpeg builds in the ndk without undue work and there's a lot you can read about on the web, but the output (or in your case input) drivers are a bit of a permissions problem.  Also you should expect encoding to be much slower than real time unless you can somehow manage to leverage hardware acceleration features of your particular device's SOC.

Answer (score 0):

if u are building your app for android then u can use .avi writer code. You can get this code from "Koders website". Search for "Koders site" on google .you will get the link. I have tested the .avi file writer code and its working fine.